# How to add apache jmeter source code (trunk code) from apache jmeter CVS repository to eclipse cvs respository?

Tags: jmeter

I need to  add trunk version of apache jmeter from apache CVS  repository  to eclipse IDE. 
        I  found some details when I was searching different  sites about to add  new CVS in Eclipse  and with  that details if try to connect it is not connecting  and not getting download any code from repository.

```
Details given to add  new CVS  detaisl in my Eclipse for apache - jmeter

Host : cvs.apache.org
Repositry path : /home/cvspublic
user name : anoncvs 
password : 
Connction type : pserver
checked in validating connection on finish option is checked.

But I am getting error like  **Error validating : "Could not connect to :pserver:anoncvs@cvs.apache.org:/home/cvspublic: cannot  locate host:cvs.paahce.org"** 

It seems like problem in host name or repository path and so on.Kindly Can any one know correct host name , repository path , username, password for successful connection   means reply me.Thanks in advance friends.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that trunk version of jmeter source code can only be accessed from subversion Repositories.

See http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterAndEclipseHowTo for the setup.

And see http://jmeter.apache.org/svnindex.html for the repository urls.